# Two monitor extended from laptop

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hp-laptop

I'm using an HP 440 G0 laptop which has one VGA port and one HDMI port. I have two monitors which both support VGA only, What I want to do is extend the laptops display to the two monitors, One with a VGA cable and the other one with a HDMI to VGA converter. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will, however the laptops display may be disabled depending on your CPU and GPU. On my HP DV6-6117dx this is the case only two monitors can be active, however on my Lenovo G50-80 this is not the case as it supports three displays at once. Again this is greatly based on you GPU but also your CPU.

Comment: I have Intel I5 CPU and intel hd4000 in my laptop. Is it enough?

Comment: Yes that should be enough.